# Probability of a specific sequence

Tags: probability

I was preparing for my probability exam and i came across this problem. A fair dice is rolled until either 6 comes up or two $5$ comes up in a row.

For example some of the possible outcomes are 
$$52546, 6, 36, 3251541355, 55, 255 \,\, \text {etc} $$

Find the probability that the last number to come up is a $6$.

I have attempted to solve this problem this way.
Let $X$ be the number of times the die was rolled to obtain two $5$ in a row and $Y$ be the number of times the die was rolled to obtain a $6$. Intuitively i thought that there could be a  $c$ such that $c(P(Y=n)) = P(X=n)$ . Then

$$1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X=n)+P(Y=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty cP(Y=n)+P(Y=n)=(1+c)\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y=n)$$

$$\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y=n)=\frac {1} {1+c}$$

However i am unable to find such a constant $c$. Any help / insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Calculation using a Markov chain gave me a probability of 7 / 8, you should be able to find c now.

Comment: Is this a question about a conditional probability? (The probability that the last result is 6 provided that the last result was a 6 or the last two results were fives?

Comment: @zoli It's the probability that the last digit ends with a 6. It's not asking for conditional probability.

Comment: @bobbym How did you arrive to the probability of 7/8

Comment: In addition to my solution below, I have been trying to understand your working. I have a number of questions. **(1)** Are $X, Y$ intended to be the first times at which $55$ and $6$ are rolled? So you want to compute $\textbf{P}[ Y < X]$? **(2)** Given these interpretations it seems to me that you want: $\textbf{P}[Y = n] = \frac16 \textbf{P}[X = n-1]$, where we condition on the $(n-1)$st roll being a $5$. **(3)** Can you explain the first sum on the left hand side of your sequence of equations.

Comment: 1) Yes , $X$ and $Y$ are meant to be the first time. 2) Yup ! that's also helpful. 3) The dice stops being rolled when we obtain $55$ or $6$.This can happen in $1,2,3,4...$ number of rolls.$P(X=n)$ is the probability of the number of times taken to obtain $55$ and $P(Y=n)$ is the probability of the number of times taken to obtain $6$. So $\sum P(X=n)+P(Y=n) =1$.Note $P(X=n)+P(Y=n)$ is the probability that the rolling of the dice stops in $n$ goes.

Comment: At the moment it seems to me as though the definitions of the variables $X, \, Y$ need to be clarified. Is $\{Y = n\} = \{\text{ first 6 rolled occurs at time n}\}$, or is it $\{Y = n\} = \{\text{first 6 rolled occurs at time n, and no 55 rolled }\}$? If it is the former then the sum you say equals $1$ actually equals $2$. If it is the later then the equation **(2)** is not true (note in the original I had accidentally interchanged the notation of $X$ and $Y$).

Comment: In addition to these points: have you actually checked your hypothesis $c \textbf{P}[ Y = n] = \textbf{P}[X=n]$? You should be able to write down these probabilities for $n=1,2,3$... which in turn should make you doubt the hypothesis. Have you looked at the method I provided below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative method of solution. In the following I will write $A\, \text{b.} B$ to denote the event that $A$ occurs before $B$. So you want to calculate $\textbf{P}[ 6\, \text{b.}\, 55]$.

Instead we work with $\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6]$, and condition on the event $5\, \text{b.}\, 6$. So
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6] & = \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6]\, \textbf{P}[5 \, \text{b.} \, 6]
\\
& = \frac12 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6].
\end{align}
To evaluate the remaining probability, we condition a second time: this time conditioning on what the roll immediately after the $5$ is.
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6] & = \sum_{j=1}^6 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is $j$} ] \textbf{P}[ \text{next roll is $j$}] \\
& = \frac16 \sum_{j=1}^6 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is $j$} ] \\
& = \frac16 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is $6$} ]  \\
& \qquad \qquad + \frac16 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is $5$} ] \\
& \qquad \qquad + \frac46 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is neither $5$ or $6$} ] \\
&= \Big( \frac{1}{6} \times 0 \Big)+ \Big( \frac{1}{6} \times 1 \Big) +\frac46 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is neither $5$ or $6$} ] \\
& = \frac16 + \frac46 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6],
\end{align}
in the final lines we used that
$$\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6\, | 5\, \text{b.}\, 6 \text{ and the next roll is neither $5$ or $6$} ] = \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6],$$
which is true since the information that we saw a $5$ but it wasn't followed by a $5$ doesn't tell us anything about the event $55 \, \text{b.} \, 6$. So substituting this into the first equation we have
\begin{align}
\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6] & = \frac12 \Big( \frac16 + \frac46 \textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6] \Big) \\
& = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{4}{12}\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6].
\end{align}
Rearranging gives: $\textbf{P}[55 \, \text{b.} \, 6] = \frac18$, and hence 
$$\textbf{P}[6 \, \text{b.} \, 55] = \frac78.$$

**Remark.** In general this type of problem is more easily phrased in the context of a Markov chain, for which the probability you are wanting becomes a hitting probability. The proof above is essentially exactly the same as would be done using Markov processes, the exception being that the notation is simplified in that context.

Answer (score 1):

The absorbing chain matrix is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{} & o & 5 & 55 & 6 \\
 o & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} \\
 5 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
 55 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The states have been labeled o which represents a throw of (1,2,3,4), 5 which is the first 5 thrown, 55 which is 2 5's in a row and 6 which is the first 6 thrown.

$$ \text{Q=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\text{R=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \frac{1}{6} \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\text{0=}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now B is the probability of ending in some absorbing state (first row) starting in some transient state (first column).

$$\text{B=}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \text{} & 55 & 6 \\
 o & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{7}{8} \\
 5 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

When we check the element o,6 we see the answer of $ \frac{7}{8} $